# Get a file with a "mixed case" name from a website URL with a lower case string

Tags: php

I know this seems confusing but what I want to do is to get a file with a "mixed case" name from a website URL with a lower case string. For example my variable which is the "lower case string" is:

```
$string = "gooddog.html";
```

The website's url is a "mixed case" which means it is mixed with lower case and upper case letters, something like:

```
$url = "http://www.example.com/GoOdDOg.html";
```

The problem is that I need to get the URL from the string, but it seems impossible as the string is lower case and the url has a mixed case.

Sorry if this is confusing, but please try to understand it, I can't explain it better.

Also, I haven't tried anything, because I have been thinking for hours of something to try, but I couldn't think of anything, sorry.

Comment: How is it that you know the file name, but not the case of the name?

Comment: I don't think that's possible unless the url resides on a Windows server. If you don't know the case of the characters your really don't know the name.

Comment: @PatrickQ it's a user input, which is gotten from my website that will redirect to another website with a mixed case

Comment: So tell the user that the value is case-sensitive.  In terms of URLs/URIs, "gooddog.html" is _not_ the same as "goOdDOg.html", and the user should not expect them to act the same (and it is your job to make sure that they do not have that expectation).

Comment: normally URI are case-sensitive (RFC 3986). So `gooddog.html` !== `GoOdDOg.html`. You should check all possible permutations of the string, but that's insane.

Comment: @Leggendario, I know, that's the problem.

Comment: @PatrickQ I could do that but not many users will like doing that. Also it is like a search engine I am building but just a bit different, so I still don't think users will like it that way

Comment: Then you need to index the pages of example.com and normalize the uri in your way

Comment: Having a user input a specific page name isn't really "search". What you're doing sounds much more akin to a proxy. As I said, anyone who's expecting to receive a _specific_ page as a result, should have no objections to entering the _specific_ name (which includes case sensitivity).

Comment: @PatrickQ The thing is it is a search that converts the user's input to a specific url like from `gooddog` to `http://www.example.com/GoOdDOg`, where it gets the results from. The user wouldn't know the case of the word.

Comment: So where is the "search" actually happening? On your site or on example.com? Is `http://www.example.com/GoOdDOg` an actual static page or is it a page that does a search for "GoOdDOg" and returns the results? How do you know that `http://www.example.com/GoOdDOg` exists?

Comment: @PatrickQ `http://www.example.com/GoOdDOg` returns information on the search. Also I don't know that it exists or not, that's why I need an answer to check if it exists.

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to know which letters to capitalizes in the all lowercase string to make it look like the URL in your example. Now if you were just searching for pages on your own website you could make a list of pages (and the all lowercase variant) and force the user input to lc.